# I get "parent_id may not be NULL" when creating my Django model

Tags: python, database, django, models

I'm creating my own `Group` model; I'm not referring to the builtin `Group` model. I want each hroup to be a member of another group (it's parent), but there is the one "top" group that doesn't have a parent group.

The admin interface won't let me create a group without entering a parent. I get the error `personnel_group.parent_id may not be NULL`. My `Group` model looks like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='groups', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: So actually the title should be: Why does syncdb fail, when I add blank=True, null=True to a model field

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created the database before I added **`blank=True, null=True`** to the **`parent`** field definition. syncdb can't deal with that type of change, so Django wasn't picking up on my changes.

I deleted my database and let syncdb create another and it worked fine.

Comment: You should consider using a database scheme migration tool like South.

Comment: is there maybe a better way to do this instead of deleting the whole db?

Comment: @niklasfi If you use South you don't need to delete the db.

Answer (score 0):

Django evolution would get you out of this kind of problem without dropping your complete database